# Doing good and bad deeds simultaneously(same time). Are they both accepted?

Tags: practical-islam, islamic-basis, deeds, dhikr

Salaam aleikum.
If someone does simultaneously (or at the same time) a good and a bad deed.
**Example**: One individual simultaneously listens to quran, makes dhikr, la ilaha ilallah, Astagfirullah, Alhamdulilah and at the same time watches BBC NEWS where women don't cover properly according to Islamic rules.

My question is: Will both the good and bad deed be written simultaneously or he has zero good deed because one of the conditions for the acceptance of a good deed is that you must not be sinning at the moment that you are doing the good deed?

Answer (score 1):

At least according to Shia that I know, looking at women (their face, hairs and etc.) who are not Muslim is not forbidden as long as their dressing is not so terribly bad, unless the person looking at them has a fear of felling in sin.

Beside that, every single deed is evaluated on its own, which itself is evaluated based on the intention of the persion ... as far as I could say

Answer (score 0):

Yes as the previous person said it is not prohibited to see any uncovered woman because that sin depend on the woman but never see her with bad eye!!
It's prohibited and comes in the list of sin,but realization of doing the sin during watching such woman is enough! The other best thing is astaghfirullah if you whole heartedly repent on your son's you will be surely forgiven?